# Socket.io is not connecting with client (react.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to connect my socket.io server with the client, but I am not getting any message that it is connected or not.
I am using React.js for the front-end and node.js, express.js, and MongoDB for backend.

I don't understand whether there is a fault in the server code or in the client.
please help :")

socketServer/index.js

```
const io = require("socket.io")(6000, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("user has been connected");
})
```

socketServer/package.json

```
{
  "name": "socketServer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1"
  }
}
```

client/Messenger.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export default function Messenger() {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setSocket(io("ws://localhost:6000"));
        console.log("tadan tadan", socket);
    }, [])
 return (
        <>
          this is messenger
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are errors in both your client-side and your server side.

For `cors.origin` try storing a `'*'`. Looks like you are trying to build a real-time chat app, thus your socket server has to listen for new messages. So you can rewrite your socket server as follows:

```
const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

const PORT = 4000;
const NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT = "newChatMessage";

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  
  // Join a conversation
  const { roomId } = socket.handshake.query;
  socket.join(roomId);

  // Listen for new messages
  socket.on(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, (data) => {
    io.in(roomId).emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, data);
  });

  // Leave the room if the user closes the socket
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    socket.leave(roomId);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The article linked [here](https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-react-hooks-and-socket-io-4859c9afecb0) helped me build my real time messaging feature for my app and where I got the above code.

For connecting the client to the socket-server and receiving messages from the server, I would suggest creating a custom hook that will listen for incoming messages. Here's the example of the custom hook from the article linked above:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

const NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT = "newChatMessage"; // Name of the event
const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:4000";

const useChat = (roomId) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // Sent and received messages
  const socketRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    
    // Creates a WebSocket connection
    socketRef.current = socketIOClient(SOCKET_SERVER_URL, {
      query: { roomId },
    });
    
    // Listens for incoming messages
    socketRef.current.on(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, (message) => {
      const incomingMessage = {
        ...message,
        ownedByCurrentUser: message.senderId === socketRef.current.id,
      };
      setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incomingMessage]);
    });
    
    // Destroys the socket reference
    // when the connection is closed
    return () => {
      socketRef.current.disconnect();
    };
  }, [roomId]);

  // Sends a message to the server that
  // forwards it to all users in the same room
  const sendMessage = (messageBody) => {
    socketRef.current.emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, {
      body: messageBody,
      senderId: socketRef.current.id,
    });
  };

  return { messages, sendMessage };
};

export default useChat;
```

Hope this helped.